# Confused on MVC in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, service

I am a bit confused on what to write where in Rails.

Ideally, I will be having a view, a controller, a model. Model should be having all the business logic. But in most of the Rails applications I've seen, I've seen most of the business logic written in the Controller files.

Should we call them as controller? And what about View-models. I am talking about the datamodels that are associated for a view. I am having JSF and Swing in my mind when I say this. There every view has a datamodel associated with it, usually a bean. But here, we don't have anything like that or I am ignorant? And what about service layers, How do I implement them in my Rails code.

To summarize my questions

1. Why are business logic being
   written in Controllers in most of
   Rails code? Is this a good practice?
2. How to incorporate the view-model in
   rails, ie, data-models for view?
3. Where to put service layers in a Rails app?

Thanks

Comment: Generally business logic is in the model. Can you cite the examples of where you've seen large amounts of business logic in the controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To summarize my answers:

1. The new standard for Ruby on Rails is to place business logic in the model. This is also known as fat model skinny controller.
2. Rails doesn't enforce this approach of one data model but you can implement it if you choose. The basic scaffolding does something similar.
3. The service layers will most likely be stored within rack middleware. This allows for general filtering of requests and responses.